# Electron nativeImage create from canvas dataURL with low quality

Tags: canvas, electron

I have a canvas with 104 width 24 height. Then I create a nativeImage instance with this canvas dataurl, but got a low-quality image.

Canvas:

[image: 1]

NativeImage create from canvas:

[image: 2]

Image with Canvas dataURL(raw):

[image: 3]

NativeImage code as below:

```js
      let image = nativeImage.createFromDataURL(canvasImg);
      image = image.resize({
        width: 104,
        height: 24,
        quality: 'best',
      });
```

Canvas and canvas raw dataUrl images are clear, but nativeImage was unclear. So how do I resolve this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Generate two pictures from canvas, one is the original resolution and the other is double resolution. Name them foo.png and foo@2x.png Then use foo.png in the createFromPath method of nativeImage object to use the image.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try using `nativeImage.createThumbnailFromPath`, if you are on windows/macOS. Not sure what is going on with `nativeImage.createFromDataUrl` but this would allow you to choose a size and get back a native image as well